# What is the expected value of sequence $\{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...\}$ or $\{1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...\}?$

Tags: expected-value

I guess it is $\frac12$ as $P(0) = P(1) = 0.5$. While I was told it is $\frac13$. How to solve this type of problem?

Thank you.

Edit by advices:

$f(n) = \left\{\begin{aligned}{0, \text{n is odd natural number}\\1, \text{n is even natural number or 0}} \end{aligned}\right.$

What is the E[f(n)]?

Comment: What do you mean by the "expected value" of a sequence?

Comment: The question needs more info. You cannot have an infinite number of elements with the same non zero probability.

Comment: (1) I’ve never heard of the “expected value” of a sequence. (2) You’ve given two sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **reverse-engineered** response that finds a way of interpreting the problem by adding a plausible but **omitted** fact.

> Expected value of $\{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, \cdots \} =$ ?

**Unfounded Assumption** 
The chance of selecting the $k$-th element in the sequence is $2^{(-k)}.$

Then, the expected value is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n 4^{(-k)} = \frac{(1/4)}{1 - [(1/4)]} = \frac{1}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The expected value is the value of that term!
$$\lambda + \mu \text{ mod }2 $$ where $$\lambda = \left\{\begin{aligned}{0, \text{first sequence}\\1, \text{second sequence}} \end{aligned}\right. $$
$$\mu = \left\{\begin{aligned}{0, \text{odd term}\\1, \text{even term}} \end{aligned}\right. $$

Now, if you have either sequence, and stop it at some "random stopping point" the expected value is $1/2$.  Or, if you pick the sequence at random and stop it at $n$, the expected value is $1/2$.  Or, if you pick both the sequence and the stopping point at random, the expected value is $1/2$.